# Covariance of Linear Combination of Variables

Tags: statistics

How do you compute the following? Given random variables $X, Y$ and constants $a, b, c, d$
$$
\mathbb C (a+bX, c+dY) = bd\mathbb C (X,Y)
$$

I managed to go until
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb C (a+bX, c+dY) &= ac + ad\mathbb E(Y) + bc\mathbb E(X) + bd\mathbb E(Y) - \mathbb E(a+bX)\mathbb E(c+dY)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the right definition of covariance:
$$\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathrm E\left[ (X-\mathrm E[X])\,(Y-\mathrm E[Y])\right].$$
Then you apply $\mathrm E[X+c]=\mathrm E[X]+c$ for constant $c$ to get rid of your $a$ and $c$ and use $\mathrm E[bX]=b\,\mathrm E[X]$ to pull out $b$ and $d$.

Comment: Thanks! I have attached the answer I think you are asking me to do.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb C (a+bX,c+dY) &= \mathbb E \left\{[(a+bX) - \mathbb E(a+bX)][(c+dY)-\mathbb E(c+dY)]\right\}\\
&=\mathbb E\left\{[a-a+b(X-\mathbb E(X)][c-c+d(Y-\mathbb E(Y)]\right\}\\
&=bd \>\mathbb E[(X-\mathbb E (X))(Y-\mathbb E(Y))]\\&=
bd\>\mathbb C(X,Y)
\end{align} 
$$